# JSON Array shows blank screen on android

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-volley, adapter

I am fetching JSON Array and trying to show it in a list view. I debugged and got that I recieve the array as required but when i run my list view is blank on android screen. When I run no error is shown in syntax or while in emulator. Here is my code:
I have used volley to call the api and fetch json data.

DashBoard.java

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RequestQueue queue;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<rowitem> arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        String url = "https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        try {
                            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("data");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("regional");
                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String location = json_data.getString("loc");
                                String totalcase = json_data.getString("totalConfirmed");
                                String recovered = json_data.getString("discharged");
                                String deaths = json_data.getString("deaths");

                                rowitem model = new rowitem();
                                model.setLocation(location);
                                model.setTotalcase(totalcase);
                                model.setRecovered(recovered);
                                model.setDeaths(deaths);
                                arrayList.add(model);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Server is not responding (Covid-19 Tracker)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        customlistviewadapter adapter = new customlistviewadapter(this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

customlistviewadapter.java

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class customlistviewadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<rowitem> arrayList;

    public customlistviewadapter(Context context,ArrayList<rowitem> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public  View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView ==  null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }
        TextView location, totalcase, recovered, deaths;

        location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        totalcase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cases);
        recovered = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.healthy);
        deaths = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deaths);
        location.setText(arrayList.get(position).getLocation());
        totalcase.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTotalcase());
        recovered.setText(arrayList.get(position).getRecovered());
        deaths.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDeaths());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just call `customlistviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `arrayList.add(model)` inside StringRequest.

Comment: It is showing Non-static method "notifyDataSetChanged()" cannot be refrenced from static context.